# Python how to raise Errors without a path

Tags: python, error-handling, path, raise

I try to raise an error without or a shorted path.

```
def stringtester(integer):
    if type(integer) != int:
        raise ValueError("this is not a integer and I only like integers!")
    else:
        print("this is a integer and I like integers!")

stringtester("this is a string")
```

logicically it raise an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Python/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    stringtester("this is a string")
  File "C:/Users/user/Python/test.py", line 3, in stringtester
    raise ValueError("this is not a integer and I only like integers!")
ValueError: this is not a integers and I only like integers!
```

but in this case the error isn't really the raise in the function. More that the function was tried to execute with a string. Is there a way to modify the path that the raise send an error without the full path like this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Python/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    stringtester("this is a string")
ValueError: this is not a integer and I only like integers!
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think by path here you mean what we usually call *traceback*, i.e. unwinding the stack back from the point where the error occurred.

There is no way to get the backtrace itself to point to anything other than the line where the error was raised (because that would be far too confusing: what line should it point to in general?).  But there *is* a convention for providing more useful error messages, which I think is the real question here:

```py
raise ValueError(f"Stringtester failed on input {integer}, which is not an integer")
```

That way although the user is taken to the `raise` line, they know *why* the error was raised.

As an aside, whilst being taken to the `raise` statement as an 'error' might strike you as odd (after all, it's doing what it's supposed to do---raising an error!) it will quickly seem normal: most (all?) languages do this.